# How to upload and download MP3 audio files in AWS S3 bucket using springboot/ java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement an application by which I will upload and download MP3 audio files in AWS s3 bucket using spring boot and java. Could some help me to get the things done. It would be very helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the [Amazon SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html). Just declare an `S3Client` bean that you'll use for your upload.

Comment: Audio files are similar to any other file, you use S3Client in SDK to upload it.

Comment: What's your exact problem? What did you try? How did it fail? Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

See the ***Photo App example*** in the [AWS Code Lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). It shows both Amazon S3 upload and download Java example code in a Spring BOOT app. It also uses the AWS SDK for Java V2. Here is the [DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) in case you have not worked with V2.

The example linked below shows use of PNG images; however, it will point you in the right direction. It has Java logic to upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket and likewise, Java logic to download an object from an S3 bucket.

For example, this illustration shows downloading an object.

[image]

[Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_section.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: All the Java logic he is asking for is in these AWS Doc  links.